# How to solve utf8_encode issue in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5, utf-8

If my application, i am fetching all posts data using eloquent models and sending its response as json to another application, if the post content contains any special character it is showing following error,[image]

after a long search i solved it by using

```
$post->content = utf8_encode($post->content);
```

now the problem is after sending this json to another app where data displaying in browser **special characters are not decoding** they shows as 
[image]

[image]

how can we solve this in browser, currently i am using angularjs as frontend.

Comment: what is your controller return?